# OAuth with IBM API Manager and IBM Mobile First

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-api-management

I would like to use OAuth as authorization system for my API created on the IBM API Manager (on Bluemix). Is it possible to use the IBM MobileFirst as OAuth provider? I have already tried inserting

```
mobile_first_context*/authorization/v1/authorization
```

as “Authorization URL”, after calling

```
advanced_developer_portal_context*/oauth/authorize
```

I obtain the form to insert the credentials, I enter a MobileFirst user and password (credentials are in basic user registry) but it seems to be always failing and the form is constantly visible.

What am I getting wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible through MobileFirst Platform Foundation at this time. The question should be directed at the API Manager product. You could probably open a PMR (support ticket) for that team.

Answer (score 0):

To use OAuth to the secure the APIs in IBM API Management, please see the [Securing an API by using OAuth 2.0 tutorial](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSWHYP_4.0.0/com.ibm.apimgmt.apionprem.doc/tutorial_apionprem_security_OAuth.html).  As provided in the earlier answer it is not possible through IBM Mobile First Platform at this time.